# Saving Records too sql database

Tags: sql, database, save, records

Hey I am having a problem with my save button I am trying to save an new action to an action table in an sql database but I am getting to separate errors one is conversion string to type integer is not valid, this is for the `.ActionTypeID = cmbActionType.SelectedValue` which is a dropdown list but is a  lookup_table in the database and the other is `@Member` is expected and is not given I thought i have done this with this line of code  `ActionLoadRecordsBindingSource.Filter = "MemberID = " & lblMemberIDValue.Text` but it does not seem to be working, here is my code below... Any ideas?

```
Private Sub tsbSaveAction_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbSaveAction.Click

    ' Error Checking
    On Error GoTo Err_tsbSaveAction_Click

    With objAction
        .ActionID = lblActionID.Text
        .ActionDateTime = dtpActionDateTime.Value
        .ActionTypeID = cmbActionType.SelectedValue
        .Notes = txtNotes.Text
        If .SaveAction = True Then
            MsgBox("Action Data saved successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "AztecCRM - Member Action")
            pnlPayments.Enabled = False
            nudSubscriptionYear.Value = Year(Now)
            dtpPaymentDate.Value = Now
            cmbPaymentMethod.SelectedIndex = 0
            txtAmount.Text = ""
            txtReference.Text = ""
            tsbSavePayment.Enabled = False
            ActionLoadRecordsBindingSource.Filter = "MemberID = " & lblMemberIDValue.Text
            Me.Action_LoadRecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me._ICOM_Actions.Action_LoadRecords)

        End If
    End With

Err_tsbSaveAction_Click:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        sErrDescription = Err.Description
        WriteAuditLogRecord(Me.Name, "tsbSaveAction_Click", "Error", sErrDescription)
        MsgBox("System Error occurred" & Chr(13) & "tsbSaveAction_Click" & Chr(13) & sErrDescription, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "AztecCRM - Error Reporting")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to include your markup and include the VB or ASP.NET tag to ensure that developers who have experience with the code side will be more likely to see this.

Comment: If `ActionLoadRecordsBindingSource` is a data source, what is it calling? I'm guessing from the error it's a stored procedure, in which case you would need to assign a parameter with the name `"MemberID"`. The drop down list error could be multiple things, is the value being returned an empty string? is the value definitely a string formatted integer? parsing will probably help if the latter is the case, parsing to a nullable integer before assigning might help otherwise (as I previously said, the markup may aid in solving your problem, more code also might be helpful e.g. what is `objAction`)

Comment: Yes it is a stored procedure and i have a parameter name MemberID thats why I am quite confused .. no it sould not be returning an empty string see the lookup table has a primarykey ActionTypeID with an other field called Description and im using another store procedure to call the description to the combo box cmbActionType.SelectedValue ... the objAction is the Action Class  Dim objAction As New clsAction